# TOC contains "Contents" in Mainfile document / DRAFT-Background without using package

Tags: table-of-contents, external-files, format-files, draftwatermark

if this question has already been asked, just let me know!
I seperated a big document into smaller files and my table of content displays "contents" as the first entry and I want to delete it. I also have a draft watermark in my whole document without using zhe package for it? Heres a MWE

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[demo,export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.5}
%titlepage
\import{./}{Titlepage.tex}
\includepdf{something.pdf}
%Acknolwedgements
\import{./}{Acknowledgements.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak
%Abstract
\import{./}{Abstract.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak
%Table of contents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{1}
\import{./}{Introduction.tex}
%Methods
\import{./}{Material.tex}
%Results
\import{./}{Results.tex}
%Diskussion
\import{./}{Discussion.tex}
%bibliography
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's the code of the titlepage that has been added into the mainfile:

```
% !TEX root = Mainfile.tex 
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\textbf{\huge Title}
\vfill
text \hfill\\
\medskip
Name
\vfill
WG
\medskip
Professor 
\vfill
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.png}
\vfill
\textbf{date}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{background}` is responsible for the word "draft".

Comment: `\usepackage{tocbibind}` is responsible for the "Contents"  line in the table of contents. Remove it and this line will be removed. If you nevertheless want your "References"  to show up in the table of contents, you could use `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` instead of `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Oh thanks @leandriis ! I saw it somewhere else to display the logo of my university on the titlepage. Is there an alternative for that? Or an option to put it off?

Comment: Please prepare a complete and self-contained [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you used the `background` package in order to add the university's logo to the titlepage. If you want a background image to only be shown on the first page of the document, you could probably make use of the `firstpage` option.

Comment: The code for the titlepage you included doe not need the `background` package at all. Remove it from your preamble, the `graphicx`  package you also load is sufficient here.

Comment: Then I get an "undefined control sequence" error for the begin document line in my main file

Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs ...urce@extgs@plain 
                                                  {#1}
l.33 \begin{document}

Comment: Try to compile again and see if the error persists.

Comment: Yes, I also deleted all other files like aux, and toc, the error still occurs.

When I force it to compile, I get an almost empty page before the title page with only /TRP1¡¡/ca 1/CA 1¿¿ on it

Comment: With the information you provided so far, I can't reproduce this error message.

Comment: Use the `nottoc` option to `tocbibind` to not add the Contents line in the ToC. ``\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`. Check the manual about other options.

Comment: @leandriis `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} does not add Contents to the ToC and will add the bibliography. There are other options to further control the package's behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the `tocbibind` package which automatically adds the titles of the ToC, LoF, LoT, Bibliography and Index to the ToC listing. It can do some other things as well. There are package options to switch off these. To not add the ToC title to the ToC listing:

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

To not add the ToC, LoF, LoT and Index titles to the ToC listing:

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot,notindex]{tocbibind}
```

Read the manual (`> texdoc tocbibind`) for more information.